# JavaScript - setInterval not executing inside do-while loop for each iteration

Tags: javascript, setinterval, do-while

So I'm trying to emulate that old memory-based game Simon with Javascript.

I'm currently trying to have 'Simon' generate randomized commands to be 'played' back (lighting up a div, and playing back audio). I wrote a function which takes a list/array of commands as input, which Simon plays back with 1 second in between each command playback using `setInterval`.

```
function go_simon(simon_array) {

    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval( function() {

        var current_val = parseInt(simon_array[counter]);
        switch (current_val) {
            case 1:
                TL_lightOn();
                var interval_1 = setTimeout( function() { TL_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 2:
                BL_lightOn();
                var interval_2 = setTimeout( function() { BL_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 3:
                BR_lightOn();
                var interval_3 = setTimeout( function() { BR_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 4:
                TR_lightOn();
                var interval_4 = setTimeout( function() { TR_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter >= simon_array.length) 
            clearInterval(interval);

    }, 1000);
}
```

I have this function placed inside a `do-while` loop which serves as the main game loop, in which a random command is generated and appended to the ongoing list of commands, and the 'go-simon' function is called which plays back the current list of commands.

I had intended for each loop iteration to consist of:

```
 •Generate random command (1-4)
 •Append to running array of commands
 •Playback array of commands over time duration - # of commands * seconds
```

Instead, the loop... loops without executing the go_simon function over however many seconds. I capped the loop to 10 iterations with an `alert()` for each iteration. This results in the alert being called 10 times in rapid succession and go_simon() being called just once at the end, playing back the array filled with 10 commands.

```
do {
    // create int 1-4 and append to global array
    generate_value();

    alert(simon_array);
    go_simon(simon_array);

    if (simon_array.length >= 10) {
            alert(simon_array);
        condition = false;
    }
} while (condition);
```

Any suggestions on how to get this `do-while` loop to have the go_simon function properly execute for each iteration?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `go_simon` let you know when it's done, because it works asynchronously. Only then you should generate a new value and call it again (possibly after a certain delay).

You can do that by making the function take a callback, to be invoked when you clear the interval:

```
function go_simon(simon_array, callback) {

    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval( function() {

        var current_val = parseInt(simon_array[counter]);
        switch (current_val) {
            case 1:
                TL_lightOn();
                var interval_1 = setTimeout( function() { TL_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 2:
                BL_lightOn();
                var interval_2 = setTimeout( function() { BL_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 3:
                BR_lightOn();
                var interval_3 = setTimeout( function() { BR_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
            case 4:
                TR_lightOn();
                var interval_4 = setTimeout( function() { TR_lightOff() }, 600);
                break;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter >= simon_array.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
        ;

    }, 1000);
}
```

Don't use a synchronous loop, let the function be called again from the callback, until the condition is met:

```
function run(){
    generate_value();
    if (simon_array.length < 10) {
        go_simon(simon_array, run);
    }
}
run();
```